# Thunderbird as a client for MS Exchange 2013, specifically GAL searches

Tags: thunderbird, microsoft, ms-exchange

I'm involved in a project at work looking at using Linux Desktops for as yet to be specified users...  One of the general use issues that I can't yet resolve is searching Global Address Lists using Thunderbird.  I have email working using IMAP/SMTP and calendaring using Lightning and Exchange EWS plugin.  I can't, however, get anything out of GAL.  This is what I've been basing my attempts on:  http://exchangetips.us/2013/03/accessing-the-global-address-list-from-mozilla-thunderbird/

Has anyone had any success in getting GAL searches to work?  Any tips would be much appreciated!